# Regular Expression for poorly defined key value pairs

Tags: regex

I am using regular expressions to parse a text files that look like the following:

```
<diagnostics> data=filenames/sometimes with/spaces\filename with or without spaces.dat start=0 end=90 overload=2 offset=871

<region> data=another file.filetype <diagnostics> replay=true
```

I would like to find all data names by scanning individual lines. If there were no spaces in the folder or filenames I could match against `data=` and then scan until a space with pattern:

`data=([^ \n]*)`

I might scan until a `.xxxx` filename is found, but in theory periods can be part of the folder or partial filenames. The actual pattern is to scan until `data=` is found and then keep going until end of line or until either one of the following: `<`, `unknownTagNoSpaces=`.

```
<stuff> data=(folder one/folder\value I want.whatever) (unknownTagNoSpaces)=
<stuff> replay=false data=(value I want followed by newline.xxx)
data=(folder/value I want.hhhh) <something>
```

So the regular expression might be to stop:

`data=[^/\n|=|</]*`

and this almost works except in the case of the equals sign `=` I have to omit the word (no spaces) and space before the equals sign as well so `data=value.docx otherkey=something` removes `otherkey` from the match.

Is this possible with regular expressions? I think the answer might be no.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood what you want, so here is my try:

```
data=((?:(?> *[^ \n<=]+)(?!=))*)
```

It uses *atomic groups*, i hope your regex engine supports it.

Explanation:

```
data=((?:(?> *[^ \n<=]+)(?!=))*)     whole regex
data=(                         )     match 'data=' and the stuff behind it as first capture group
      (?:                    )*      repeat as long as the contained stuff is valid
         (?>           )             atomic group: treat as one part, don not break apart, "tokenize"
            ̺ *                       match all spaces here (has some nice effect explained later)
              [^ \n<=]+              match (at least one) symbol that is not newline, '<' or '='
                        (?!=)        ensure there is no equal sign
```

The atomic group captures preceding whitespace and all valid symbols thus stopping at spaces.
Since spaces are captured beforehand there will no trailing whitespace, however leading whitespace must be matched (but can be excluded from the capture group) because the 'data=' prefix is also part of the match.

The atomic group magic happens when the '=' is encountered. It is not allowed in the atomic group and if it is found to be behind it the entire group will be discarded.
In this case the group consist of the attributes name and the spaces in between.

[Example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ezbyt5/1)

Answer (score 1):

I thought about a solution without atomic groups:

```
data=((?: *(?![^ ]+=)[^< ]+)*)
```

Explanation:

```
data=((?: *(?![^ ]+=)[^< ]+)*)    whole regex
data=(                       )    match 'data=' and the stuff behind it as first capture group
      (?:                  )*     repeat as long as the contained stuff is valid
         ̺ *                       match all spaces here
           (?![^ ]+=)             check that no "attribute" (no-space followed by '=') comes next
                     [^< ]+       math all the valid symbols
```

This regex basically checks for all text that appears that it is not followed by '=' and then matches it.

[Example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SeqeDy/1)